# Store procedure not working with Linq to SQL, in view

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I am newbie to MVC 3 and LIN to SQL and i am trying to call Store procedure 'GetAttendance_Sp' from database via DataContext, i successfully did it but now problem is in view, it throws error:

```
Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.GetAttendance_SpResult' to type 'EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.EmployeeAtd'.

Source Error: 


Line 10: 
Line 11: <ul>
Line 12:  @foreach (EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.EmployeeAtd emp in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model) 
Line 13:  {
Line 14:      <li>@emp.EmplName</li>
```

code:

```
using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models;
namespace EmployeeAttendance_app.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Employee Attendance";
            var DataContext = new EmployeeAtdDataContext();
            var EmployeeAtd = DataContext.GetAttendance_Sp;
            return View(EmployeeAtd);
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (EmployeeAttendance_app.Models.EmployeeAtd emp in (IEnumerable<Object>)ViewData.Model) 
 {
     <li>@emp.EmplName</li>
 }
</ul>
```

even though i did same for hardcore select query and worked fine but not for SP, why ?

explain that why view not working for SP but for Simple select query even though both return same result sets ?

Comment: Help would be appreciated

Comment: Apparently your sproc returns `GetAttendance_SpResult` and you've got an `EmployeeAtd` as view model.

Comment: what output is given by sp, show some sp code

Comment: can you try something like this? EmployeeAtd em= new EmployeeAtd(); and cast the result from the SP to the property of newly created object.

Comment: @GertArnold question raised in my mind, Why it appends Result to the name of store procedure ? and why does it behaves like CLASS ? since Object model stores SP as method.

Comment: ? any insights on it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while that I worked with linq-to-sql, but after a quick refresh I found out that you can change the result type of a stored procedure in the dbml designer, like so:

[image]

Of course, in your case you should select the type `EmployeeAtd`.